# knitr code chunk option to hide roxygen comments

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, roxygen2, beamer

Would it be possible to add some new code chunk option in order to
hide roxygen comments (beginning by `#'` or `##'`) in the chunk?

My motivation is that I use **knitr** to create beamer slides from a
`.Rnw` file. I process this file with `knitr::knit2pdf` to get a pdf
file and also with `knitr::purl` to get an R file related to the
slides. It would be great if I could use in my code chunks **roxygen**
comments that would show only in the R file produced by `purl` but not
in the pdf, where code chunks must be very concise.  Then I could
transform my R file with the great `knitr::spin` to get a rmarkdown
file with the code chunks comments turned into plain rmarkdown text.

For example the following code in a beamer `.Rnw` file

```
% One slide
\frame[containsverbatim]{
We now show how to use the of \verb@each@ formal of the `rep` function.
<<myChunk, roxcomments.hide="knitr2pdf">>=
##' Using the `each` formal of `rep`
rep(1:2, each = 3)
@      
}
```

The roxygen comment `##'` would not be shown in the pdf, but would eventually be shown in the rmarkdown code

````
Using the `each` formal of `rep`
```{r myChunk} 
rep(1:2, each = 3)
```
````

Of course, it would not be complicated to make a script skipping
roxygen comments in the `.Rnw` file before proceeding it with
`knitr:knit2pdf`, since roxygen comment marks do not seem to interfer with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses the [`source` output hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/output-hooks.html) to filter out lines starting with `#'` or `##'`.

The hook is only "active" if the chunk option `hideRoxygen` is `TRUE`. The actual filtering of the output occurs in the line `x <- x[!grepl("^#'|^##'", x)]`. After this, the default hook (saved in `hook_old`) is executed, as recommended in the link above.

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE}

hook_old <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("source")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  if(!is.null(options$hideRoxygen) && options$hideRoxygen) {
    x <- x[!grepl("^#'|^##'", x)]
  }
  
  hook_old(x, options)
})

```

```{r, hideRoxygen = TRUE}
#' A sample function
#'
#' @param x A parameter that will be ignored.
sampleFunction <- function(x) {
  return(NA)
}
```
````

Output:

```
sampleFunction <- function(x) {
  return(NA)
}
```

Comment: Originally, I was trying to use `echo = [vector]` as suggested in [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68022726/2706569) but set the value of `echo` dynamically, based on the value of `opts_current$get("code")`. However, I could not figure out how to set `echo` from within a hook for the current chunk, even with `eval.after`. I'd love to see an answer that demonstrates such a solution!

Comment: Thanks, it works with `.Rnw` code as well! I changed  the test into `if (!is.null(options$hideRoxygen) && options$hideRoxygen)` and it works so that the check no longer crashes. This solution makes easy to use a script with an argument to hide roxygen comments.

Comment: You are right. The `is.null` check is smarter than setting the option by default.

Answer (score 4):

I just recently learned that in regards to basic .Rmd file that you can use `echo=2`  to remove comments that are within R chunks.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Daniel"
date: "6/17/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, echo = 2}
# comment
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

I am not 100% sure about your .Rnw results with my answer, as I try to stay with .Rmd files for my own needs.

[image]

Comment: An useful feature indeed, which works with a `.Rnw` code. Yet I would like to discard *only roxygen comments*. With your indication I think it would be easy to discard all comments in chunks using a variable for the chunk option `echo`.  This variable can even be a parameter in a script.

Comment: It seems that the `echo` chunk option can be (beside the better known `TRUE` and `FALSE`) an integer vector giving the lines of code  to be echoed.